# Display suite fields visibility restriction

Tags: display-suite

Is there a way in DS fields visibility restriction with url pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can create a custom view mode with DS, add or remove fields as you wish, configure that view mode to use a DS layout, then access the view mode through a URL.

The structure looks like this for the "full" view mode: node/x?v=full.

You need to enable a DS Extra setting called "View mode per node" at admin/structure/ds/list/extras